Flutter web SEO
How bad is Flutter web SEO? flutter.dev says that flutter is not very SEO friendly (as V. 3) But I'm wondering if I could bring up my app first page on google when user search the web app name.
I've reached out flutter community on LinkedIn and telegram groups yet I have not found my answer.

Never heard of Flutter web SEO - but this is off topic here as its a recommendation request.

Take a look at this if you are creating single page applications and what you can do to have better SEO: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/javascript/javascript-seo-basics

man!
SEO for Flutter web applications, starting from version 3, can be a real headache, especially if you're aiming to get your site to the top of search engine results. The issue lies in the fact that Flutter creates single-page applications (SPAs) that rely on client-side rendering, meaning the content is generated using JavaScript. Despite the efforts of search engines, they still don’t always index such pages correctly.
One of the main problems is that search engine bots struggle to properly crawl and index your app's pages, which can lead to poor visibility in search results. Since Flutter doesn’t support server-side rendering, all the content is generated on the client side, and search engines might not even see it, making your SEO efforts more difficult.
Additionally, setting up important SEO elements like title, description, and keywords meta tags in a Flutter app is challenging because you don’t have the same level of control as you would with traditional HTML sites. This makes optimizing for search engines significantly harder.
However, you still have a chance to rank well, especially if your web app has a unique name and minimal competition. You can create a static HTML page with traditional SEO optimization that links to your Flutter app. This can help attract the attention of both users and search engines. Another strategy is to build backlinks from authoritative sites to your landing page or domain to improve visibility.
Flutter supports PWAs (Progressive Web Apps), which can help improve indexing and increase the app’s visibility. It’s important to optimize the aspects of your app that are within your control, such as improving load times, using descriptive URLs, and ensuring that content is accessible for indexing.
While Flutter web might not be the most SEO-friendly framework, that doesn’t mean your app is doomed to invisibility. By using creative strategies and understanding the limitations, you can improve your chances of getting your app indexed and ranked, especially for unique and less competitive queries like your app’s name.

Flutter Web has significant SEO limitations because it renders content on a canvas instead of traditional HTML, making it harder for search engines to index your app. This can affect your app's visibility on search engines like Google. To improve SEO, consider creating a separate HTML landing page for search engines to index, using deep linking, or adopting a hybrid approach with SEO-friendly pages outside of Flutter. While you can still rank for your app's specific name, it's challenging to achieve strong SEO results with a full Flutter Web app alone.
